# How to edit pom.xml in eclipse except as a raw XML?

Tags: eclipse, maven, eclipse-plugin

I am new to Maven and Eclipse. It seems the `m2e` plugin doesn't provide a GUI to **fully** customize the pom.xml. Such as:

- Add a plugin to `<build>` element
- And add `<license>` element
- Add `<developer>` element

Do I have to edit pom.xml as an raw XML file in eclipse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See `pom.xml` tab in the end in visual editor, click on it

[image]

Comment: Thanks! But is there some more user-friendly UI than plain XML editor?

Comment: the one you see in screenshot is developer friendly, no ?

Comment: Anyway, I can live with it. :)